# Container for firmware file: collection of binary data parts

Tags: java, c++, data-structures, firmware

I need to generate firmware file for embedded device, and I'm wondering what are the best practices of the format of data structures like that.

There should be several items in that file: firmware for MCU, some data parts to be written to the device flash memory.

The obvious way is to implement that format "by hand": some header at the start of the file (header should contain version of data structure), then address table, and then data. That's the way I used in previous projects, and I'm really tired of maintaining this structure when I need to change something.

Is there some existing container to store data collections in the binary file? There would be nice to have library for many platforms (at least, C++ and Java) that can handle this data collection. What comes to mind is SQLite database file with one or several tables, but it seems to be overhead for my needs.

Is there some best practices to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, The most common format is ZIP or in Java terms JAR.  This can be browsed in Windows Explorer and read on a wide variety of platforms.

Comment: I'd add some meta-info header in front of the zipped data when it's supposed to be stored at a certain flash address.

Comment: ZIP files are read from the end of the file.  This allows unpacking programs to contain the ZIP. i.e. the program to do the unzip is at the start and the ZIP is at the end.  You can pre-pend any amount of data to the ZIP and it will function normally.  I suggest however, adding meta information as file(s) of a given name(s) to make this easily accessible. (This is what JAR files do)

Comment: If you have an OS that allows self extracting executables, yes

Comment: In any case, all this works with the standard ZIP format. In your case, there could be any amount of meta data at the start of the ZIP, and it would still work as a ZIP file.  The trick is you need a utility to build such a file.  If you have the meta data in the ZIP, any existing ZIP utility can build the file.

Comment: Although it has been some time since the originl question - the topic hast not been completely covered here. Original question was about the update file format (container) for embedded solutions (OS-less systems with RAM size less than FLASH). So, parsing zip-container is not an option. One has to store the update "on the fly", as soon a new chunk of the update has been received. I struggle with the same problem re-inventing formats all the time, despite the year 2021. Have not found any decent alternative yet for myself. I would be thankfull for any hint in or success story here. Regard.

Comment: @OpalApps for really tiny systems, you want something as simple as possible. However, you get a lot of power these days for very little money.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you for taking the time to comment. More concrete suggestion (with tool/library/format name in it) would be appreciated, though.

Comment: @OpalApps you can't get any simpler than a raw file which is in the form you can use it in memory. This could be memory mapped for example. To create this you could have an application build a data structure in memory and then copy it to disk, making sure you avoid pointers or to handle them approximately (i.e. by loading the data into the same address space)

Comment: @PeterLawrey The original question (and my interest) is in existing formats and respective tooling, not improvised ones. Besides what you describe covers uniform address spaces only. Without memory layout information and partitioning mechanism inside update image you can cover with simple image file only trivial single-mcu-builtin-flash cases.